# How to filter requests so that apache handles them and not tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

For various reasons I want to shutdown my server after a certain period of idle time. I am running Tomcat 8.5.29 and Apache2 (not sure the version) on Debian 4.9.88. I wrote a script to look at the last time Tomcat had an access. I only have one app on the server and it is at `http://hostname/source/`.

My problem is that there are a number of webserver vulnerabilities out there and I am getting a constant flow of requests to:

- `GET / HTTP/1.1`
- `POST /GponForm/diag_Form?images/ HTTP/1.1`
- `GET /jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor?action=inspectMBean&name=jboss.system%3Aservice%3DMainDeployer HTTP/1.1`
- `POST /user/register?element_parents=account/mail/%23value&ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax HTTP/1.1`

What I would like to do is stop anything that doesn't begin with `/source` from even getting to Tomcat. I presume that a rewrite or something in Apache can do it, but I am not sure how the requests get to Tomcat in the first place. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways for requests to reach Tomcat:

1. The probes send requests directly to the Tomcat port (typically port 8080). You can fix this by restricting Tomcat's listening address to the loopback address, by adding the attribute `address="127.0.0.1"` to the corresponding Connector element in `conf/server.xml`. Or you can just block port 8080 in your firewall.
2. The requests are forwarded from Apache to Tomcat via a reverse proxy configuration in Apache. This means there is a line such as the following in one of the Apache configuration files:

   `ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

   If you add an explicit path prefix to both arguments, you can restrict which requests are passed to Tomcat:

   `ProxyPass /source http://127.0.0.1:8080/source`

   This ensures that only requests that begin with "/source" are forwarded to Tomcat.

   Some Apache configurations use the AJP protocol instead of HTTP for proxying, but the same reasoning applies.